# Second window appears in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The program works however,  when I made sure that the error part, which should only appear if `circles.dat` (which contain a list of int) however, a second window of the failed (done purposely to test the error object) object still appears as a small window.

```
from tkinter import *
class Error():

    def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()#Tk
            self.root.title("ERROR-PAGE")#name on bar
            self.root.resizable(0,0)#doesn't let it be resized

            self.gamefield = Canvas(self.root, width=320, height=480, bg="black") #canvas

            self.top = Frame(self.root)
            self.gamefield.create_text(20, 60, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25),text="We have",fill="white")
            self.gamefield.create_text(20, 100, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25),text="had",fill="white")
            self.gamefield.create_text(20, 140, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25),text="a",fill="white")                        
            self.gamefield.create_text(55, 140, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25,"bold"),text="BAD TIME",fill="cyan")            
            self.gamefield.create_text(20, 180, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25),text="finding 'circles.dat'",fill="white")
            self.gamefield.create_text(20, 220, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25),text="Please place the",fill="white")
            self.gamefield.create_text(20, 260, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25),text="file in the",fill="white")
            self.gamefield.create_text(20, 300, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25),text="same folder as",fill="white")
            self.gamefield.create_text(20, 340, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25),text="the file",fill="white")
            self.gamefield.create_text(20, 390, anchor=W, font=("Comic Sans MS", 25),text="'my_circle.py'",fill="white")
            self.gamefield.pack(side="top")
            self.root.mainloop()



class Mycircle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()#Tk
        self.root.title("My Circle")#name on bar
        self.root.resizable(0,0)#doesn't let it be resized

        self.gamefield = Canvas(self.root, width=640, height=480, bg="white") #canvas

        self.top = Frame(self.root)
        self.count=0#count
        try:            
            with open("circles.dat", "r") as f:
                self.text = [int(a) for l in f for a in l.split()]
        except:
            Error()
        while self.count < len(self.text):
            try:
                self.gamefield.create_oval((self.text[0+self.count]),(self.text[1+self.count]),(self.text[2+self.count]),(self.text[3+self.count]), outline="gray",fill="red", width=2)
                self.count+=4
                self.gamefield.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
            except:
                print("there wasn't enough int to finish another circle")
                self.count+=4
        self.gamefield.pack(side="top")
        self.root.mainloop()#loop



def Main():
    Mycircle()

Main()
```

Comment: A tkinter app should never have more than exactly one instance of `Tk`. If you need additional windows you need to create instances of `Toplevel`

Comment: And what is the problem?  Do you want 'Error" in the same window?